# Get SubjectDescriptor for AAD group

Tags: rest, azure-devops

I am trying to add an AAD group to an Azure DevOps Project Team. Research shows that this can be done via the following REST URL:

`PUT https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/memberships/{subjectDescriptor}/{containerDescriptor}?api-version=6.0-preview.1`

I can get the containerDescriptor for the Team. But question I have is how do I retrieve the AAD group subjectDescriptor to use in the above URL? It begins with "aadgp."

Thanks in advance,
Jake

Comment: I went about this a different way. 
Added group using objectid to DevOps 
$uriAddAADGroup = "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/$($OrganizationName)/_apis/graph/groups?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
$groupConfig = @{"originId"= "980b68d1-1792-4950-850b-30372382d667"} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriAddAADGroup -Method Post -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader -Body $groupConfig -ContentType "application/json"

This gives the Descriptor in the response.

Comment: If the AAD group is already in DevOps, use 
https://vssps.dev.azure.com/$($OrganizationName)/_apis/graph/groups to get the descriptor.

Then I think you can just add a member to the team with the descriptor

Comment: Ignore my comments above and go for the answer I posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok..got it working

Get the group descriptor for the Azure DevOps group separately then use it below

```
$groupDescriptor = "vssgp.blahblahblah"
$uriAddGroupToTeam = "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/$($OrganizationName)/_apis/graph/groups?groupDescriptors=$($groupDescriptor)&api-version=6.0-preview.1"
$groupConfig = @{"originId"= "{Get Group GUID from AAD"} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriAddGroupToTeam -Method Post -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader -Body $groupConfig -ContentType "application/json"
```

Thanks
Jake.

Comment: Hey @JakeUT, thanks for the answer. Can you explain how to get the `$AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader `?

Comment: You need to generate a Personal Access Token in the DevOps portal first

Then you can do this

$AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($AzureDevOpsPAT)"))}

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use  [Groups - List API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/groups/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

`GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/groups?api-version=6.0-preview.1`

It gets a list of all groups in the current scope (usually organization or account).

The optional parameters are used to filter down the returned results. Returned results are in no guaranteed order.

Since the list of groups may be large, results are returned in pages of groups. If there are more results than can be returned in a single page, the result set will contain a continuation token for retrieval of the next set of results.

If above is not work, you could also use web portal to add AAD to a Azure DevOps group/team, then use F12 to track Network session and check API details.

[image]